# Drupal modify translation of error message

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, internationalization

i have an English Drupal installation but the frontend needs to be dutch. Now i asked a few weeks ago if it's possible to install a different backend and frontend language but this seems to be difficult. Now i only have one small message that isn't translated yet in the frontend and this is the required field error message (... field is required). How can i edit this translations? The may be an easy not so clean solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an english backend and Dutch frontend you should use [admin language](http://drupal.org/project/admin_language) that should fix that problem for you. In regards to translating the field required, that should be simple enough. It use a placeholder, so you might need to look for something like

> @field is required

Drupal use this system when it use the same string with a dynamic value so you only need to translate it once and not for every combo.

Answer (score 0):

thanks, for the admin_language module, but i found how to do this simple translation. You can override the translations using 'String overrides' ins settings.php